# Git hook to automatically rename files after updating repository

Tags: git, githooks

My team and I have set up a git repository containing a PHP web application on a Linux server that we regularly push to. We already use a post receive hook to inform the whole team via email whenever someone pushes something, which works just fine.
Additionally, we checked out this repo to a different location on the same server and use this as "staging area" for other colleagues. The web application needs to load a "config.php" file that contains machine specific information (e.g. absolute paths), so its contents depends on the server and location it runs on. Therefore, there are several config files inside the repo:

- config.sample.php (for developer machines)
- config.live.php (for the live server)
- config.staging.php (for the staging area)

The file "config.php" was added to .gitignore, so it is not part of the repo.
What we want to achieve is the following automation: whenever someone pulls the staging repo, the existing file "config.php" gets deleted and the file "config.staging.php" is copied as "config.php". This way, we want to make sure that changes to the config files are automatically updated in the staging area.

Do we have to set up a hook in the "main repo" or in the "staging repo"? Which hook (e.g. post-receive) do we have to use?

Comment: A few comments... You can achieve the same with symlinks, which I guess behave better. On another app, I created a full config file, and inside there were several sections, and the app itself was picking one based on some env_var that software received. That could be also the current git branch name. And I also did once to do this copy/move/delete on the CI, so file is always the same. To work specifically on hooks, there are git hooks management tools you can find at https://githooks.com/ (disclaimer: I am the author of hooks4git). Hope this might get you some ideas...

Comment: Thank you so much, Lovato! We never worked with symlinks, but this obviously solved our problem and makes things even easier than our original plan.